# LocationManager does not call, DIdEnterRegion , didExitRegion does not called

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am developing a Reminder App,i have enable geofencing in that App. the Region Radius is 100m, when the user entered into that location, DIdEnterRegion does not get called, even i leave that location,didExitRegion also get not called. Only startMonitoringRegion is only Called.Here is the Code

```
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
self.locationMeasurements = [NSMutableArray array];

_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[_locationManager setDelegate:self];
[self stopMonitorSpecificRegion];

if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

_locationManager.distanceFilter = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"radialDistance"]?[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"radialDistance"] doubleValue]:kCLDistanceFilterNone;                          // whenever we move
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"desiredAccuracy"]?[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"desiredAccuracy"] doubleValue]:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is issue with ios 8 Add this to your code

```
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
{
    [locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

and to info.plist:

```
  <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
  <string>I need location</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>I need location</string>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>I need location</string>
```

Comment: i have already added this to my code, but still does not get any alert of notification.

Answer (score 0):

If [locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization] also doesn't work then click on xCode project, goto target settings and in the Capablities tab click on **Background Modes** and enable Location Updates.

And here on the above code, you haven't created instance for CLRegion and you should call startMonitoringforRegion method to monitor a region.Below is an example for it. Try this:

`CLLocationCoordinate2D region = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9877899, 13.88999);
CLCircularRegion* regionToMonitor = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:region radius:500 identifier:@"address"]; 
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:regionToMonitor];`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:yourregion];
}
```